# python 2.7 defining a class that will show their attributes if called with no arguments

Tags: python, class

I have  a class like this:

```
class DATA:
    # class for the data
    def __init__(self, filename):
        f_in = open(input_file, 'r')
        data = json.load(f_in)
        f_in.close()
        # organizational data
        self.T = data['temperature']
        self.appVersion = data['appVersion']
```

I can create an object of the class with:

```
D = DATA(filename)
```

I can access the attributes with

```
D.T
```

The class will have a lot of attributes, and I will soon forget their names... What I need is to have a a prompt with some helpful information if I call `D` alone.

For example:

```
>>>D
The attributes of D are:
- T (X)
- appVersion (Y)
```

where `X` and `Y` are the corresponding values.

Is there a build in way to make this happen? Or any other (better) approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you print them in `__init__` and put the same in docstring?

Comment: This sounds like a good use for `__repr__`.

Comment: implementing docstrings and using `help` is by far the best way. for something closer to what you want, if you use ipython, you can also get the docstring (+ other info, including arguments) with `D?` (use ? after object). If you're dead-set on the above interaction, though, you could abuse `__repr__` to accomplish this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that precise functionality, what you get when you type

```
>>> D
```

is the `return` value of `DATA.__repr__(D)`:

```
class D(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
    def __repr__(self):
         s = "The attributes of D are:\n- T ({0.T})\n- appVersion ('{0.appVersion}')"
         return s.format(self)
```

Example usage (with overridden `__init__` to take `data` directly):

```
>>> D = DATA({'temperature': 102, 'appVersion': '1.0.4'})
>>> D
The attributes of D are:
- T (102)
- appVersion ('1.0.4')
```

However, you should note that this is an abuse of what `__repr__` is for; from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__):

> If at all possible, [`__repr__`] should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned.

The other answers are, thus, more Pythonic.

Comment: This will accomplish exactly what @otmezger asked for. But, you probably shouldn't do it. About ``__repr__``, the [Python documentation says](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html): *Called by the ``repr()`` built-in function and by string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).*

Comment: @tsroten that is a good point, I will add a disclaimer to my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can document the attributes in the docstring:

```
class DATA(object):
    """this says something about the object.

    Attributes:
      T: ...
    """
    ...
```

Now you can access the documentation that you wrote by:

```
help(DATA)
```

or:

```
print(DATA.__doc__)
```

Comment: Good idea. That definitely fits the bill for "helpful information", however, it's lacking the values of the actual attributes.

Comment: @tsroten -- Sure.  also helpful might be to just print `vars(D)`.  That'll give you the attribute name and the value.  Sometimes I like to put it in a loop:  `for k, v in sorted(vars(D).items()): print k, v`

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about the ``vars`` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `__dict__` attribute:

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'value 1'
        self.bar = 'value 2'

d = Data()
print(d.__dict__)
```

That prints:

```
{'bar': 'value 2', 'foo': 'value 1'}
```

To access it on the prompt easily, try this:

```
def info(obj):
    print(obj.__dict__)
```

Then at the prompt, just type:

```
info(d)
```

Comment: I like this because it prints the actual values.... `help(DATA)` won't. But any idea how to acces this function by entering just `D` on the prompt? Is this possible?

Comment: See the other answer for the note about ``__repr__``. That's how you can accomplish the behavior you want.

Comment: See @mgilson's comment about ``vars(D)``. That's an easier way to get the object's attributes and values.